# More than one Foreign Key to the same table?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am trying to save  a foreign key in 2 columns of a row. For some reason, this is acting wonky because some of the navigation properties are showing up as columns in my table... Here is the model. What am I doing wrong?

```
 public class BorrowedPerson
    {
        public int BorrowedPersonID { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> PersonID { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> CompanyID { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> TempCompanyID { get; set; }
        public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
        public virtual Company Company { get; set; }
        public virtual Company TempCompanyID { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Basically, when I am using more than one of the virtual attributes, it creates a column named TempCompanyID_Company and CompanyID_Company

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out... Very simple answer. When you are specifying more than one navigation property to the same type, it requires you to manually specify the foreign key like so.

```
public class BorrowedPerson
    {
        public int BorrowedPersonID { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> PersonID { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> CompanyID { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> TempCompanyID { get; set; }
        public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("CompanyID ")]
        public virtual Company Company { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("TempCompanyID")]
        public virtual Company TempCompanyID { get; set; }
    }
```